# pmp6712 active buck snubber operation

Tags: voltage, buck, snubber

I need to design a clamp circuit in order to clamp the ringing voltage of a square wave. Therefore, I am planning to use the circuit given below. This circuit belongs to TI however, I couldn't get any reply so far. Could someone please briefly explain me how does the circuit given below operate?

Kind regards,

Mert.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the cure is worse than the rather lightweight disease. Maybe try explaining why you'd want to do this?

Comment: I have a DC/DC converter which has 18V and 72A output. At the secondary side I have a rectifier unit. Due to the rectification process there are voltage spikes at the output of rectifier. I would like to limit these voltage spikes. It is possible to use zener diodes as well however it reduces the efficiency and causes heating. I read that this circuit limits the voltage spikes and at the same time it gives the energy stored in the spikes to the output of the circuit which increase the overall efficiency 1%.

Comment: _”Due to the rectification process there are voltage spikes at the output of rectifier”_ What leads you to that assumption rather than the usual suspects - parasitics? Show layout. Show oscillograms.

Comment: @winny Right- In the TI reference design the spikes are mainly due to the leakage inductance in the transformer.  Other parasitics contribute as well.

Comment: @JohnD Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hysteretic buck converter riding on Vout.  When the voltage at "snub" reaches 75V (riding on Vout so 129V wrt ground) D22 avalanches.  R99 conducts current at that point.

If the voltage drop across R99 is enough to reach the threshold of the buffer, U15, the buffer turns on the PFET Q27, storing the energy from the spike in L5.  When the voltage drops sufficiently to turn off Q27, D24 turns on (as in a conventional buck converter) and L5 continues to deliver that energy to the output. This cycle repeats for each spike. 
Note that the current in D24 is limited by R99 and R105 in order to scale the voltage across R99 appropriately.  R100 limits current into the buffer input in case of excess input voltage.

The entire circuit is powered from the energy in the spikes, and D21 ensures that the supply voltage to the buffer doesn't exceed the maximum voltage capability of the device.

C81 provides decoupling and energy storage for the circuit.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation! However, there is one point that I didn't understand. In order to turn on a P-FET we need to have a negative Vgs and positive to turn it off. In this circuit it seems like the voltage over source of Q27 is always higher than voltage over gate which seems like the P-FET is always on. Am I wrong?

Comment: The buffer supply U15 pin 1 is directly connected to "snub".  The source of the PFET is also directly connected to "snub".  When no current is flowing in R99 due to the 75V zener being off, the input to the buffer will also be at the same potential as "snub", meaning that the output of the buffer will be high, close to the supply rail, and close to the source connection of the FET.  So Vgs is close to zero in that case and the FET is off.

Comment: thanks a lot again! these answers are very helpful. One last thing, since the rail voltage of Buffer is 6.8V, the output of the buffer is 6.8V as well right? The thing is after the SNUB exceeds 6.8V the P-FET should turn on which means above 6.8V the FET is always on. Is it true or am I missing a point?

Comment: @MertKaradeniz The ground of the rail for the buffer is regulated to be 6.8V BELOW the source of the FET, whatever that is. Note that the GND pin of the buffer is not connected to Vout, but is isolated by the 47K resistor. So SNUB can't rise more than 6.8V above the ground of the rail of the buffer.